# Are public instance methods that are not overridden dynamically bound?

Tags: java, dynamic, binding, static, overriding

I have a question about method binding. As you know, binding of private, static and final methods happen at compile-time, while binding of overridden methods happen at runtime.

In the following, we have a method `something()` in `Parent`, which is not overridden in the corresponding subclass `Child`.

```
class Parent {
    void something() {
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Parent p = new Child();
        p.something(); // still dynamically bound?
    }
}
```

Is the call of `p.something()` in our main program (although it is not overridden) still dynamically bound?

Comment: You seem to be confusing some things. The method signature is determined at compile time. Method binding is always done at runtime. The exact rules are defined in [JLS §15.12.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12)

Comment: If you're talking about v-table lookups (used to facilitate dynamic dispatch), those can be eliminate by the JIT compiler if the method is not overridden. But small methods like getters and setters, are pretty much always inlined any ways.

Comment: But the binding of a static, private or final method is done at compile-time, isn't it? Ok, those methods cannot be overridden. However, the binding of a virtual method (which can be overridden) is always dynamically. The lack of an override doesn't change it. From the given answers I understand it that way.

Comment: Due to dynamic linking, there is no way to know at compile time whether a method is overridden, so you will always get an `invokevirtual` in the byte code

Comment: Yes, this is a good explanation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the method signature is determined at time of compilation. However, method binding is always done at runtime. The exact rules for the runtime dispatch are defined in [JLS §15.12.2.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5).

So as you are probably guessing now, the call of `p.something();` is still dinamically bounded.

As a sidenote, check out [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)) to clearly understand polymorphism.

Comment: Ok, since the type of our created object is determined at runtime the method binding will be done dynamically (regardless of whether an override of that method exists).

Comment: @NurettinArmutcu thats it. Mark as answer if it'd helped you.